# Use Vars in included File, don't work in 2. step

Tags: php, include, php-include

I try to use a variable in a included file.

In standart this work:

```
t1.php ->
<?php
 $x = 100; 
 include_once(t2.php);
?>

t2.php ->
<?php echo $x; ?>
```

But if I build a loader between this two: to have a easyer handling, it don't work. This look like this:

```
t1.php ->
<?php
 include_once("t3.php");
 $x = 100; 
 load("t2");
?>
t3.php ->
<?php
   function load($file){
       $path = "./";
       include_once($path.$file.".php");
   }
 ?>
t2.php ->
<?php echo $x; ?>
```

Has someone an idea?

Comment: That's because your loader is a function, so the variables in the files that are included inside that function exist only in the scope of that function

Comment: @MarkBaker ok cann i get it out of this? or how could i change the loader?

Comment: Simple answer, there's no way to avoid it, variable scope exists.... why not simply stick with include_once; your loader isn't really adding any value to the inclusion